# Server side rendering json data using NodeJS, Express, Handlebars and expbhs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

So I was having trouble server side rendering some JSON data using ExpressJS and Handlebars and also using the expbhs view engine.  Given the following:

obj:

```
[
 {
  prop1: 'value',
  prop2: 'value',
  prop3: 'value',
  prop4: 'value'
 },
  prop1: 'value',
  prop2: 'value',
  prop3: 'value',
  prop4: 'value'
 }
]
```

Controller:

```
exports.displayData = (req, res) => {

    //assume valid json
    res.render('myTemplate', {
        obj
    });
}
```

My handlebars template (myTemplate.hbs) looks something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
    <div class='section'>
        <div id="{{prop1}}-section" >
            <div>
                <img src='{{prop2}}'>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class=''>
                    stuff{{prop3}}
                </div>

                <div>
                    other stuff: {{prop4}}
                </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    Data for: {{prop1}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

This will render the template but no property values will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was wrapping my obj in another obj in my `res.render()` call, so I changed the call to:

```
exports.displayData = (req, res) => {

    //assume valid json
    res.render('myTemplate', obj);
}
```

This partially solved the answer.  I was getting all the obj data populated, but it was also rendering extra `.section` `<div>`s with empty property values.

So I tried the following:

In my controller, I changed the `res.render()` json parameter to `{ data: obj }` like so:

```
exports.displayData = (req, res) => {

    //assume valid json
    res.render('myTemplate', { data: obj });
}
```

and in my template I changed my `#each` block from `this` to `data` like so:

```
{{#each data}}
    <div class='section'>
        <div id="{{prop1}}-section" >
            <div>
                <img src='{{prop2}}'>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class=''>
                    stuff{{prop3}}
                </div>

                <div>
                    other stuff: {{prop4}}
                </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    Data for: {{prop1}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

My guess is that either exphbs or handlebars adds properties to the `obj` by default and those properties were being passed in `this` when it was rendering the document.  That would explain the empty `<div>`s

I figured this out because I was planning on swapping my layout to something else for that particular render, and to do that it would have looked like this:

```
exports.displayData = (req, res) => {

    //assume valid json
    res.render('myTemplate', { 
        data: obj,
        layout: 'nonDefault'
    });
}
```